# VBA: Copy one value, paste it down the row for fixed number of times and then repeat

Tags: vba, excel, copy, data-cleaning

I am working on cleaning weather data available online on Canadian Government website. The problem sounds simple but unfortunately I couldn't get what I want via VBA.

WHY DO I HAVE A PROBLEM?

To clean data, I want to see if there is relationship between weather and moods.

The data is divided in sections (i.e one section by station for one year). Each section of the data has daily weather information (365 rows, 366 for leap year) in tabular form. The station name is nowhere mentioned in that data. It is only mentioned in one cell at top of each section. So I want to copy the station name from the header section and paste it down the row for all the days.

For-example:
If there are 8000 stations in canada that are monitoring weather data daily, then there will be 8000 sections of tables, each section will have daily weather data.

Here's my query in steps:

1) Copy one value of cell(cell B1) and paste it down the row 4694 times range(AC27:AC4720). 4694 covers 10 years +section headers, empty spaces.
2) Move down one extra row (so leave AC4721 blank)
3) Start the process again.
     The function has repeat the process till the end of the file.

Formula in simple language:

continuing after blank space....

the cell is at AC4722 now, relative to this cell the formula has to copy the value of B4696, repeat step (1) and step (2) of the query.

In this way the next will AC9417, relative to this cell the formula has to copy the value of B9391, repeat step (1) and step (2) of the query.

The difference between relation positions (AC27,B1), (AC4722,B4696), (AC9417,B9391) is always 26

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To input the value all you need to do is:

```
Range("AC27:AC4720") = Range("B1")
```

No need to iterate over each row.

The hardest part is working out the range that you need to copy it to. Which can be done many ways depending on how your file looks.

Comment: Thank you ClintB for the answer.

This is range of cells, This pattern will go on for 8000+ stations

(Station,B, AC)(1, 1, 27)(2,4696,4722)(3,9391,9417)(4,14086,14112)(5,18781,18807)(6,23476,23502)(7,28171,28197)......   
    
Is it possible to code the series like a loop or something?

Comment: You need some sort of identifier that a new station is starting. Is there a column that always has "Station name:" or something similar, you can then search for that. Work out the range between the first found station and the second found station, then set the range equal to the station name.